# prevent MVVM ServiceAgent event hooking up multiple times

Tags: wcf, events, mvvm

Developing a Silverlight application that is communication with a WCF Service.

MVVM -> ServiceAgent -> WCF Service

So in my ViewModel i have:

```
ServiceAgent.SearchExternalPatients(Name, (s, e) => 
            { 
                ExternalPatients = e.Result;                    
            });
```

in my service agent i have:

```
public void SearchExternalPatients(string name, EventHandler<SearchPatientExternalCompletedEventArgs> callback)
    {                          
        _proxy.SearchPatientExternalCompleted += callback;
        _proxy.SearchPatientExternalAsync(name);
    }
```

The problem is each time i click on the search button it hooks up the event again, and when i get the result back i receive it several times.

What is the best way to unhook these events in the MVVM ServiceAgent pattern?

Comment: If i place a "_proxy.SearchPatientExternalCompleted -= callback;" before the "_proxy.SearchPatientExternalCompleted += callback;" is solves the issue. But is this the best way?

Comment: This works as long as callback is the same delegate each call, which it likely is. But do you want to depend on that coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

```
public void SearchExternalPatients(string name, EventHandler<SearchPatientExternalCompletedEventArgs> callback)
{
    EventHandler<SearchPatientExternalCompletedEventArgs> wrapper = null;
    wrapper = (s, e) =>
    {
        callback(s, e);
        _proxy.SearchPatientExternalCompleted -= wrapper;
    }                          
    _proxy.SearchPatientExternalCompleted += wrapper;
    _proxy.SearchPatientExternalAsync(name);
}
```

You may get a warning from the compiler or ReSharper or Visual Studio's static code analysis (depending on the settings for each) because the lambda is accessing a variable that is modified outside the lambda, but this should work correctly. Though I don't see why you would factor the code this way in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Could you perhaps utilise the Reactive Extensions to do this? I have not done a lot with Silverlight but RX tends to ease a lot of the pain associated with event hooking/unhooking. Something along the lines of [this example](http://sonyarouje.wordpress.com/2010/10/31/making-async-calls-in-silverlight-using-reactive-extension-rx/).